# List from repeated items in XSLT

Tags: arrays, list, xslt, unique

I'm new to XSLT and I'm looking for help in my problem. Here is my code in XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <nadrazi jmeno="Podlešín">
        <vlak typ="os" cislo="5112" z="Hostivice" cil="Podlešín" naVlak="53001">
            <prijezd>16:20:00</prijezd>
            <slozeni>
                <vuz cislo="1" oznaceniC="810" />
                <vuz cislo="2" oznaceniC="010" oznaceniT="Btax" />
            </slozeni>
        </vlak>
        <vlak typ="os" cislo="53001" z="Podlešín" smer="Zloněves" cil="Kralupy nad Vltavou" zVlaku="5112">
            <odjezd>17:00:00</odjezd>
            <slozeni>
                <vuz cislo="1" oznaceniC="810" />
                <vuz cislo="2" oznaceniC="010" oznaceniT="Btax" />
            </slozeni>
        </vlak>
        <vlak typ="sp" cislo="1389" z="Louny" smer="Zloněves" cil="Praha Holešovice">
            <prijezd>16:18:00</prijezd>
            <odjezd>16:23:00</odjezd>
            <slozeni>
                <vuz cislo="1" oznaceniC="843" />
                <vuz cislo="2" oznaceniT="Btn" />
                <vuz cislo="3" oznaceniT="Btn" />
            </slozeni>
        </vlak>
        <vlak typ="r" cislo="572" z="Praha Holešovice" smer="Slaný předměstí" cil="Chomutov">
            Nechranice
            <prijezd>14:27:00</prijezd>
            <odjezd>14:28:00</odjezd>
            <slozeni>
                <vuz cislo="0" oznaceniC="754" />
                <vuz cislo="250" oznaceniT="B" />
                <vuz cislo="251" oznaceniT="B" />
                <vuz cislo="252" oznaceniT="Bp" />
                <vuz cislo="253" oznaceniT="Bp" />
                <vuz cislo="254" oznaceniT="BDs" />
                <vuz cislo="255" oznaceniT="A" />
            </slozeni>
        </vlak>
    </nadrazi>
```

I want get a vlaue from all elements `vlak` attribute `smer` make an array (or a list or something similar) from this values and then use something like `unique()` function to have only one item of every repeated value. In this case in my array will be "Zloněves" and "Slaný předměstí".

Here is my XSLT code. I tried some ways to create some arrays but I failed and erased that lines (some time ago).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rozpis vlaků pro stanici <xsl:value-of select="nadrazi/@jmeno" /></title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(element) {
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(element);
    if(srcElement != null) {
        if(srcElement.style.display == "block") {
            srcElement.style.display= 'none';
        } else {
            srcElement.style.display='block';
        }
    return false;
    }
}
</script>
<body>
    <h1>Stanice <xsl:value-of select="nadrazi/@jmeno" /></h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="nadrazi" mode="smer" />
</body>
</html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="vlak" mode="smer">
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@smer" /></xsl:attribute>
    </div>
    <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output will be HTML file, where items of the array will be div's id (div id="arrayItem"). Now the output is (that times and spaces aren't important now but some help I would welcome (link etc.)):

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Rozpis vlaků pro stanici Podlešín</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(element) {
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(element);
    if(srcElement != null) {
        if(srcElement.style.display == "block") {
            srcElement.style.display= 'none';
        } else {
            srcElement.style.display='block';
        }
    return false;
    }
}
</script><body>
<h1>Stanice Podlešín</h1>
    <div id=""></div>
        16:20:00





    <div id="Zloněves"></div>
        17:00:00





    <div id="Zloněves"></div>
        16:18:00
        16:23:00






    <div id="Slaný předměstí"></div>
        Nechranice
        14:27:00
        14:28:00










</body>
</html>
```

and I want this:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<title>Rozpis vlaků pro stanici Podlešín</title>
</head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function show(element) {
    var srcElement = document.getElementById(element);
    if(srcElement != null) {
        if(srcElement.style.display == "block") {
            srcElement.style.display= 'none';
        } else {
            srcElement.style.display='block';
        }
    return false;
    }
}
</script><body>
<h1>Stanice Podlešín</h1>
    <div id="Zloněves"></div>
    <div id="Slaný předměstí"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Into those divs I will add more data and that ids I need for hiding divs with Javascript function `show(id)`. And all elements which have smer="Zloněves" will be in one `<div id="Zloněves">` and all elements which have smer="Slaný předměstí" will be in another one `<div id="Slaný předměstí">`

I have found some questions how to make an array but nothning solving this problem. Thanks for help.

Comment: Please post your code of your XSLT

Comment: Also, can you show the XML you want to output? Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for comments. Question was updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a grouping problem, and in XSLT 1.0 you need to use a technique called [Muenchain grouping](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html).

You are grouping **vlak** elements by their **smer** attribute, so you define a key like so:

```
<xsl:key name="vlak" match="vlak[@smer]" use="@smer" />
```

So, for a given value, the key will return all **vlak** elements whose **@smer** attribute equals that value.

Now, to get the distinct elements, you need to match the **vlak** elements who occur first in the key for their given **@smer** value. This is done like so:

```
<xsl:template match="vlak[generate-id() = generate-id(key('vlak', @smer)[1])]" mode="smer">
```

And then within this template, should you so wish, to get all the **vlak** elements with this group, just access the key

```
<xsl:for-each select="key('vlak', @smer)">
```

The only other thing you would need is a template to match the other **vlak** elements to stop them being output outside this loop

```
<xsl:template match="vlak" mode="smer" />
```

Here is the full XSLT (I've removed the javascript for brevity)

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" />
    <xsl:key name="vlak" match="vlak[@smer]" use="@smer" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Rozpis vlaků pro stanici <xsl:value-of select="nadrazi/@jmeno" /></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Stanice <xsl:value-of select="nadrazi/@jmeno" /></h1>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="nadrazi" mode="smer" />
</body>
</html>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="vlak[generate-id() = generate-id(key('vlak', @smer)[1])]" mode="smer">
    <div>
        <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="@smer" /></xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:for-each select="key('vlak', @smer)">
        <xsl:value-of select="odjezd" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </div>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="vlak" mode="smer" />
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<html>
<head>
<META http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html">
<title>Rozpis vlaků pro stanici Podlešín</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Stanice Podlešín</h1>
<div id="Zloněves">17:00:00 16:23:00</div>
<div id="Slaný předměstí">14:28:00</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi
Here i'm not giving the full code just giving the sample of fetching values

```
<xsl:for-each select="nadrazi/vlak">
    <xsl:if test="@smer='Zloneves'">
      <div id =<xsl:value-of select="@smer"/>>
        <xsl:value-of select="prijezd"/>
         <xsl:value-of select="odjezd"/>
        </div>
    </xsl:if>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

In the above example i've used the  `<xsl:if>` element `<xsl:choose>`

The sample ouput for the above code will be

```
<div id=Zloněves></div>
        17:00:00

    <div id=Zloněves></div>
        16:18:00
        16:23:00
```

Comment: Ok, this little help, but now there are two same IDs but I want only one. One `<div id="Zloněves">` and one <div id="Slaný předměstí">`. That is my main problem.